# How can I see the inside of the content box

Tags: css, css-content

Hi I was wondering how can I see what is inside this box "" in the content in the style sheet

for example : I want to know the link of the image:

```
.facebookicon::before {
    content: "";
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. That just looks like an `invalid character".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those square boxes usually mean that the Glyph that should be represented is missing from the character set of whatever program or font is being used to display the text. The only option is to attempt to open the file in another program.

Taking a rough guess it may be that the stylesheet your looking at is using a custom font and has created glyphs for various icons (this is done so that they will scale better on HiDPI screens) and assigned them to regions of the character set that is unused by normal fonts in order to avoid clashing.

In other words, It is highly unlikely there is an image.

Comment: ahaa.. Thanks a lot :D